# Meyers singleton and dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, macos, design-patterns, c++11, singleton

Does the Meyers Singleton work in a scenario with dynamic libraries?
I.e. one library defining the singleton, others using it, each in its own compilation unit?
(*I suppose it doesn't matter but the specific architecture is an application with frameworks on OS X*)

I'm using the vanilla Meyers Singleton pattern: The following `Instance()` method is defined inline in the header file for a utility class (that's defined in a dynamic library):

```
    static Logger&  Instance()
              {
                 static Logger singletonInstance;
                 return singletonInstance;
              }
```

Copy constructor and `operator=` are declared private and not implemented, so we should be good, right?

Now if I link that library defining the singleton from the main app I can see the constructor being called **multiple times**.. with different addresses for `this` and all the weirdness I would expect when not having an actual singleton but multiple instances of the class.

So I'm wondering whether the dynamic library approach screws up the Meyers singleton or whether each compilation unit - library, main app - that includes the header for the singleton (effectively declaring and **defining** the Instance() method) will get "*it's own singleton instance*"?

Really not quite sure what to make of my observations so any hints much appreciated!

Comment: Is the `static Logger& Instance()` in a header file that is supposed to be used to get the instance in other code? Why is it not `extern`?

Comment: is that the actual code? I expected `Logger::Instance()`..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, `Instance()` is defined inline in the singleton's header file. Rephrased the question to make that clearer..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to *declare* `Instance` in a header, and then *define* it in a dynamic library (presumably the same one that `Logger` is defined in).  And you need to drop the `static`.  And you need to make sure `Instance` has default visibility if you are using the [visibility tools](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

From your description, it sounds like you've defined this function in a header.  This would give everyone who includes the header their own private definition of `Instance`, and thus their own private definition of the `static Logger` within `Instance`.

You could declare `Instance` `inline`, and that would give everything the semantics you expect (same as declaring in header and defining in the dylib).  But my recommendation is to just do the inline to confirm what I'm telling you is correct (it is easy), and then outline into a dylib (and confirm again).

Once outlined, your design should work fine.

That being said, it is only guaranteed to work in C++11.  That is, local statics are not thread safe in C++98/03, but are in C++11 and later.  However, on OS X, they are thread safe even in C++03 language mode as an extension.

One other caveat:  If you access `Instance()` in the atexit chain (or in a destructor of a global object), it is possible that your access will occur after the destruction of the static local `singletonInstance` within `Instance()`, causing undefined behavior.  If you don't register things with `atexit()`, and if your global destructors don't call `Instance()`, you're safe.  Otherwise you aren't.  If you aren't safe, you can purposefully leak it:

```
Logger&  Instance()
{
   static Logger* singletonInstance = new Logger;
   return *singletonInstance;
}
```

This may cause some memory leak checkers to report false positives (or maybe they are true positives depending on your point of view), which is irritating.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Dropping `static` only in the definition, right? I.e. wouldn't make any sense to remove it from the declaration?

Comment: Drop `static` from the function declaration *and* definition.  `static` in this context means "file scope" or "private to the file."  And you want the scope of this function to be application wide.